# QuickBooks plugin installed in CakePHP 3 does not load

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0

I have added the Quickbooks Online PHP SDK to my `composer.json` file in CakePHP 3:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "3.5.*",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
    "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
    "cakephp/plugin-installer": "~1.0",
    "josegonzalez/dotenv": "2.*",
    "friendsofcake/cakepdf": "@stable",
    "friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui": "@stable",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "@stable",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.*",
    "quickbooks/v3-php-sdk": "@stable"
},
```

I ran the composer update, and the SDK was loaded into the `vendor/quickbooks folder`.
I updated my `cakephp-plugins.php` file to:

```
return [
    'plugins' => [
        'Bake' => $baseDir . '/vendor/cakephp/bake/',
        'BootstrapUI' => $baseDir . '/vendor/friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui/',
        'CakePdf' => $baseDir . '/vendor/friendsofcake/cakepdf/',
        'DebugKit' => $baseDir . '/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit/',
        'Migrations' => $baseDir . '/vendor/cakephp/migrations/',
        'Quickbooks' => $baseDir . '/vendor/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk/'
    ]
```

and added:

```
Plugin::load('Quickbooks');
```

to my `bootstrap.php` file.
When I load my home page and look at the loaded packages, the QuickBooks SDK is not listed, but the `friendsofcake/cakepdf` package is.

In my app Controller class I have:

```
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\ServiceContext;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\PlatformService\PlatformService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\Http\Serialization\XmlObjectSerializer;
```

but when I try to create a DataService object I get the error:

> Class QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService not found

Comment: QuickBooks is not a CakePHP plugin, and [**the actual FQN**](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/tree/v3.3.0#configuration) is `QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService`.

Comment: ndm - so does that mean that you can not load ANY non-cake plugins using composer? Since the QuickBooks SDK has a PS4 load section in its `composer.json' file the same as the other plugins I have installed, I expected it to still load.

Comment: Composer is for installing code. Any composer-compatible package can be installed with it. Only things that conform to Cake's plugin structure can be loaded with `Plugin::load`.